# Accessing current element of *ngFor Loop in TypeScript Code (Angular 4)

Tags: json, angular, loops, typescript, ngfor

I have an array of 5 persons in my json file. Each person has an array with items in it.
In my html code, I'm using *ngFor to loop through the persons to show their name. I also want to show the sum of the prices of the items.
To calculate the prices of their items together, I use a function in my TypeScript code. I'm showing the total of the prices in my console.

The problem is, that the current code I'm using in my typescript file loops through the persons again. So I'm looping through the persons in my html with ***ngFor** and in this I'm calling the function **getTotal()**, which loops through the persons **again**. Of course I want to loop through them only once.

**json**

```
  "persons":[
    {
      "name": "Peter",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "pen",
          "price": 1.50
        },
        {
          "name": "paper",
          "price": 2.00
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Maria",
      "items": [
        {
          "name": "scissors",
          "price": 4.00
        },
        {
          "name": "stickers",
          "price": 3.00
        }
      ]
    }

    // three more persons
  ]
```

html

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons"> <!--here I'm looping through the persons-->
  <p>{{person.name}}</p>
  <p>Total <span>{{getTotal()}}</span></p> <!--here I'm calling the function, which will loop through persons again-->
</div>
```

typescript

```
getTotal() {
    for(let person of this.persons){ //here I'm looping through the persons again (what I actually don't want)
      let total = 0;
      for(let item of person.items){
          total = total + item.price;
      }
     console.log(total);
    }
}
```

**Now to my question:**
As you can see, I was looping through persons in my html code with *ngFor and in my typescript code in getTotal() again. I only did that to access their items in the following loop (**person.items**). I wanna get rid of the first loop and access the current element I'm looping through with *ngFor. How can I achieve this or is it even possible?

Comment: I would do the calculations in component before display, mainly because calling a method in the template is generally a bad idea as it is called on each change detection.

Comment: Please check updated answer , Implemented as @Alex just told in comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Change It like

> As answer to your question , call a function from template side , here
>   it is but would prefer second method to go

**Template Side :**

```
<p>Total <span>{{getTotal(person.items)}}</span></p>
```

**Component Side :**

```
getTotal(items) {
    let total = 0 ;
    for(let item of items){
        total = total + item.price;
    }
    return total;
}
```

---

> Better way to do is , process all data from component side , rather than calling it from template side
>
> Why ?
>
> In above case function will be called each time the view changes or data change.

**Component Side :**

```
constructor(){
    this.persons.map(person => {
        person.total = person.items.reduce((pv,cv) => {
            return cv.price + pv.price;
        });
        return person;
    });
}
```

**Template Side :**

```
<p>Total <span>{{person.total)}}</span></p>
```

Comment: ok, thanks for the updated code. But to be honest, I'm very new to TypeScript and I don't really understand what your code does. I don't understand what "person.total = person.items.reduce((pv,cv) =>" does. Could you give me a short explanation, please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Okay then would suggest to checkout the reduce function of javascript (pv - previousValue , cv - currentValue)

 , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I understand the function better

Comment: Hi again. I tried your code, but I'm getting the error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: @BlueCat , Code inside the constructor is just sample , you should call that part when `persons` is initialised , you are getting error coz you are trying to call that before initialisation of `persons`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass person in the `getTotal` function and can add the price of the items in that without looping again

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons">
  <p>{{person.name}}</p>
  <p>Total <span>{{ getTotal(person) }}</span></p> <!--here I'm calling the function, which will loop through persons again-->
</div>
```

Typescript

```
getTotal(person) { 
      let total = 0;
      for(let item of person.items){
          total = total + item.price;
      }  
      return total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Send to the getTotal method the person. I mean:

```
getTotal(person:any){
   let total: number = 0;
   for(item of person.items){
       total += item.price;
   }
   return total;
}
```

So in your HTML it must be:

```
<div *ngFor="let person of persons"> 
   <p>{{person.name}}</p>
   <p>Total <span>{{getTotal(person)}}</span></p> <!-- take a look how 
       I send the current person in the *ngFor loop -->
</div>
```